# Temporary animation over image after clicking it (Angular 13)

Tags: css, angular, image, animation, click

I'm working on an Angular 13 application with a quite simple combat system, in which you can attack enemies by clicking their images, and I'm looking a way to achieve a "hit effect" to represent damage whenever you click on their images. Something like turning the image to red for one second, with a CSS rule like this one:

`filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(35%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(-50deg) saturate(534%) contrast(1.3);`

I don't know if this can be done with Angular animations, or maybe just by CSS animations applying a rule on (click) function that is called after clicking on the image, or even with some kind of hidden overlay which could show up for X seconds somehow with a `setTimeout()` call. So, I would appreciate any help on how to achieve something like this in a clean and elegant way. Thank you so much for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, we could animate it back and forth using `setTimeout`. I would prefer Angular animations if you want more control how, when or why animation is triggered. Css option is always there of course - a class could be applied with `NgClass`.

Html

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <div (click)="isHit(item)" [@removeImage]="item.show">
      <img [src]="item.href" />
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    // the animation
    trigger('removeImage', [
      state(
        'true',
        style({
          filter: 'hue-rotate(-50deg)',
        })
      ),
      transition('false<=>true', [animate('0.3s 0.0s ease-in')]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  items = [
    {
      name: 'A',
      show: true,
      href: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91-Db4L6xjL.png',
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      show: true,
      href: 'https://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Funny-pictures-of-animals-41.jpg',
    }
  ];

  isHit(item: any) {
    item.show = !item.show;
    setTimeout(() => {
      item.show = !item.show;
    }, 300);
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-when-removing-clts3h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html